# How to deal with user_id at iOS(swift)-rails app using Facebook SDK for iOS

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, facebook, omniauth

I'd like to get user_id of the user who login on mobile app by Facebook SDK.
Please tell me the following idea is good or not.

1) It is got facebook_id of user by FB SDK for iOS.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios

2) On server-side, it is made User model and FBUser model, FBUser model is child of User model.

3) It is checked the facebook_id user exists or not on server-side.

4) If the user exists, api tells the user_id. If the one doesn't exist, the new User model is made, then api tells the user_id.

I'm worried that it is bothersome.Especially, to check whether the facebook_id user exists or not is troublesome.
I expect that to user Omni-auth login for rails is one option.

My purpose is following.

1.To login by FB
2.To set serial number for user who login by any method(email, Fb and other omni-login)

If you know better way, please advise me. Thx your kindness.

Comment: Hmm I am unable to follow what you are describing but if "get user_id of the user who login on mobile app by Facebook SDK" is your question then all you have to do is make a call to https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/me?fields=id&access_token='user-access-token' once the user logs in. This will give you the app-scoped user id which is maybe what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you Bangdel! I'll try it:)